# how to update table on yii 1 using chtml dropdown and javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, yii

i want to  change table value using chtml dropdown, if i used on cgridview, it works well. but when i have costumize table, it doesnt work. here is my code :

my chtml code :

```
<?php
echo "Period: ".CHtml::dropDownList('list_period_active', $id_periode,$list_period_active);
?>
```

my table code :

```
<table width="75%" border="1" id="box-table-a" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">column 1</th>
        <th scope="col">column 2</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
$typeprogress = Period::getProgressType();
$i=0;

foreach($typeprogress as $type){
    $i++;

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$type.'</td>';

}
?>
</table>
```

my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#list_period_active').change(function (){
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('penilaian-ptsp-periode-grid', {
            data: {'period':$('#list_period_active').val()}
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to explain _why_ it doesn't work, or rather what occurs versus what you would expect.

Comment: i have table like above, i want change table using chtml dropdown. ex : if i choose 2015  on dropdown, the table will show 2015 data. if i choose 2016, the table will show 2016 data. it work when i use cgridview, but when i create manual table like above, it doesnt work.